# How does the topology of the graphs' Riemann surface relate to its knot representation?

Tags: graph-theory, knot-theory, riemann-surfaces, zeta-functions

Let's consider the following bipartite cubic planar [non-simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) graph

$\hskip2.3in$[image]

Looking at the orientation of the edges around the vertices, it is obvious that left and right are oriented opposite.

Now blow up every edge like in a [ribbon or fat graph](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ribbon+graph). Including the change of orientation the resulting graph looks like:

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

where I stuck to the convention that I flipped every fat graph edge in the same direction. The resulting knot is a trefoil.

Further, the bicubic planar graphs can be related to Riemann surfaces (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3424936/19341) and references therein). Is there a relation between the Riemann surfaces and the knot?

> How does the topology of the graphs' Riemann surface relate to its knot representation?

Concerning the construction of Riemann Surfaces, I can't judge which is the most promising. I collected a bunch of constructions [(any additional ones are welcome here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3424936/19341):

- Grothendieck's [Dessin D'Enfants](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2709419/19341)
- Makover's [Approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626800/19341)
- Hurwitz's [Way](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3034043/19341)
- Nieser's [Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2047672/19341)

but I can't judge which one fits best to knots. If I'm forced to pick, I'll pick Hurwitz.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: The computation of the rank and Ihara zeta function for this graph seem to be irrelevant to the actual question. I recommend editing that out and adding a self-contained description of the construction of a Riemann surface that you have in mind.

Comment: @j.c. I removed the rank computation, but I'm not able to choose a specific construction of a Riemann surface...

Comment: Suppose that the initial cubic plane graph has a cycle of odd length.  Then the fat graph will not be orientable.  So the surface is not a Riemann surface.  So, I don't understand the actual question here...

Comment: @Sam I edited my question, accordingly...

Comment: The question is not clear to me. It is true that for any planar graph you can associate a knot diagram, using the algorithm you described. But I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Henry the only choice I make, is how to orient the "fat edges" in the fat/ribbon graph. See also Def. 1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311458.pdf).

Comment: What I want to know: Since the knot construction of bicubic graph deals with orientations at the vertices or between pairs of vertices, Makover's construction of the Riemann Surface of a (bicubic) graph, seems to be based on similar grounds. I wonder about the relation of the knot/link and Riemann surface constructed from the same graph. It looks to me that the knot/link is related to the left-hand turn paths. But what would that mean for the Riemann surface?